# /n new line error in C

Tags: c

I have just written a program (very simple one) but I have a little silly problem: when I enter **/n** to show the output in the next line, the output keeps showing all in one line and prints the **/n** too.

Here's the part of the program I'm talking about:

```
printf("Your gross salary is: %0.2f /n", GS);
printf("The amount of your income tax is: %0.2f /n", Taxes);
printf("Your net salary is: %0.2f /n", NS);
```

and this is what it prints:

Your gross salary is: 400.00 **/n**The amount of your income tax is: 60.00 **/n**Your net salary is: 340.00 **/n**

Does anyone know why this is happening and would be whiling to help me??

Comment: Take the [tour, learn [ask] and post a [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

`/n` isn't a newline character. It is a two character sequence, with a `/` followed by a `n`. You need character `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

`/` is not an escape character. The escape character is `\`. With `\` you make clear that your intention is to use the next character, `n` as a newline, not as an n letter. So, use `\n`:

```
printf("Your gross salary is: %0.2f \n", GS);
printf("The amount of your income tax is: %0.2f \n", Taxes);
printf("Your net salary is: %0.2f \n", NS);
```